# GoBackToAsync('pagname") not working as expected

Tags: .net, maui, prism

stack

---

page1.xaml

page2.xaml

page3.xaml

If you use the GoBackToAsync("page1") from page3... the OnNavigatedTo is being fired on page2.  This is causing issues if there is a check for required parameters.  If causes the page to show the error message.

Expected result should be to go back to page 1 without firing the OnNavigitedTo of page 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GotoAsync` to navigate from page3 to the page1. This will not call the `OnNavigatedTo` method on page2.

Here is the code you can use:

```
Shell.Current.GotoAsync("//Page1");
```

Comment: I am not using Shell navigation.. I am using the stack navigation.  I didn't think you could mix the two ways of navigating.